# rails 3 mail gem please help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, encoding

Ok i have 2 emails one has Japanese and english in both subject and body and the other one seems to be in iso-8859-1

When i do email.subject it displays properly both in my console and browser and also saves fine in my database (mongodb). so i presume its converting to utf-8 properly.

Problem is how to get the text_body and html_body to do the same ?

If i try to save email.html_part.decoded into database i get a string not utf-8 error. Also if i do email.html_part.decoded.force_encoding("UTF-8") i still get this error.
If i do just email.html_part it lets me save into database  but does not look correct when viewing it.

comes out like this

> Content-Type: text/plain;
> charset=iso-8859-1
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
> Content-ID:
>
> =0D
> check!=0D
> =0D
> To: joe@hotmail.com=0D
> Subject: Save almost =A32,000 on a luxury Alaskan yacht holiday! =0D
> From: canada@travel.co.uk=0D
> Date: Tue, 10 May 2011 05:39:24 -0500=0D
> =0D
> =0D
> =0D
> =0D
> =0D
> =0D

and japanses one comes out like this

> Content-Type: text/plain;
> charset=iso-2022-jp
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> Content-ID:
>
> From: joe@hotmail.com
> To: sales@domain.com
> Subject: ($B%Q%s$r?)$Y$J$$!#(B) "I will not eat bread"
> Date: Tue, 10 May 2011 21:13:55 +0000
>
> Negatives are formed by inflecting the verb. For example, Pan o taberu ($B%Q%s$r?)$Y$k!#(B) "I will eat bread" or "I eat bread" becomes Pan o tabenai ($B%Q%s$r?)$Y$J$$!#(B) "I will not eat bread" or "I do not eat bread". Plain negative forms are actually i-adjectives (see below) and inflect as such, e.g. Pan o tabenakatta ($B%Q%s$r?)$Y$J$+$C$?!#(B) "I did not eat bread".

I am using rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2-p180

Please can anyone help with this ?
thanks rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first mail is 'quoted-printable', which you can unpack using `String#unpack`:

```
str = "=0D check!=0D =0D To: joe@hotmail.com=0D Subject: Save almost =A32,000 on a luxury Alaskan yacht holiday! =0D From: canada@travel.co.uk=0D Date: Tue, 10 May 2011 05:39:24 -0500=0D =0D =0D =0D =0D =0D =0D".unpack('M').first
=> "\r check!\r \r To: joe@hotmail.com\r Subject: Save almost \xA32,000 on a luxury Alaskan yacht holiday! \r From: canada@travel.co.uk\r Date: Tue, 10 May 2011 05:39:24 -0500\r \r \r \r \r \r \r"
```

You want to declare it as iso-8859-1 and convert it to utf-8:

```
str.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
"\r check!\r \r To: joe@hotmail.com\r Subject: Save almost £2,000 on a luxury Alaskan yacht holiday! \r From: canada@travel.co.uk\r Date: Tue, 10 May 2011 05:39:24 -0500\r \r \r \r \r \r \r"
```

You probably have to do the same with the second mail.

Comment: thanks   is there a way to auto get the encoding to force from the email.html_body ?     ie . force_encoding(email.htm_body.ecoding?).encode('utf-8')

Comment: Check if there's a possibility to get the encoding directly from the mail object.